# Which part of this Powershell code snippet is making it take a long time to run?

Tags: powershell, sorting, search, active-directory, execution-time

I'm tasked with making a report of the last logon time for each user in our AD env, I obviously first asked mother google for something that I could repurpose but couldn't find anything that would check multiple Domain Controllers and reconcile the last one, and then spit out if it was past an arbitrarily set date/number of days.

Here's the code:

```
foreach ($user in $usernames) {
    $percentCmpUser = [math]::Truncate(($usernames.IndexOf($user)/$usernames.count)*100)
    Write-Progress -Id 3 -Activity "Finding Inactive Accounts" -Status "$($percentCmpUser)% Complete:" -PercentComplete $percentCmpUser
    $allLogons = $AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -match $user}
    $finalLogon = $allLogons| Sort-Object LastLogon -Descending |Select-Object -First 1
    if ($finalLogon.LastLogon -lt $time.ToFileTime()) {
        $inactiveAccounts += $finalLogon
    } 
}
```

`$usernames` is a list of about 6000 usernames

`$AllUsers` is a list of 18000 users, it includes 10 different properties that I'd like to have access to in my final report. The way I got it was by hitting three of our 20 or so DC's for all users in specific OUs that I'm concerned with. The final script will actually be 6k*20 bec I do need to hit every DC to make sure I don't miss any user's logon.

Here's how `$time` is calculated:

```
$DaysInactive = 60
$todayDate = Get-Date
$time = ($todayDate).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
```

Each variable is used elsewhere in the script, which is why I break it out like that.

Before you suggest `LastLogonTimestamp`, I was told it's not current enough and when I asked about changing the replication time to be more current I was told "no, not gonna happen".

`Search-ADAccount` also doesn't seem to offer an accurate view of inactive users.

I'm open to all suggestions about how to make this specific snippet run faster or on how to use a different methodology to achieve the same result in a fast time.

As of now hitting each DC for all users in specific OUs takes about 10-20sec per DC and then the above snippet takes 30-40 min.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things stand out, but likely the biggest performance killer here is these two statements:

```
$percentCmpUser = [math]::Truncate(($usernames.IndexOf($user)/$usernames.count)*100)
# and
$allLogons = $AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -match $user}
```

... both of these statements will exhibit **O(N^2)** (or *quadratic*) performance characteristics - that is, every time you *double* the input size, the time taken **quadruples!**

---

1. ### `Array.IndexOf()` is effectively a loop

Let's look at the first one:

```
$percentCmpUser = [math]::Truncate(($usernames.IndexOf($user)/$usernames.count)*100)
```

It might not be self-evident, but this method-call: `$usernames.IndexOf()` *might* require iterating through *the entire* list of `$usernames` every time it executes - by the time you reach the last `$user`, it needs to go through and compare `$user` all 6000 items.

Two ways you can address this:

#### Use a regular `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $usernames.Count; $i++) {
    $user = $usernames[$i]
    $percent = ($i / $usernames.Count) * 100
    # ...
}
```

#### Stop outputting progress altogether

`Write-Progress` is *really slow* - even if the caller suppresses Progress output (eg. `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`), using the progress stream still carries overhead, especially when called in every loop iteration.

Removing `Write-Progress` altogether would remove the requirement for calculating percentage :)

If you still need to output progress information you can shave off some overhead by only calling `Write-Progress` *sometimes* - for example once every 100 iterations:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $usernames.Count; $i++) {
    $user = $usernames[$i]
    if($i % 100 -eq 0){
        $percent = ($i / $usernames.Count) * 100
        Write-Progress -Id 3 -Activity "Finding Inactive Accounts" -PercentComplete $percent
    }
    # ...
}
```

---

2. ### `... |Where-Object` is *also* just a loop

Now for the second one:

```
$allLogons = $AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -match $user}
```

... 6000 times, powershell has to enumerate all 18000 objects in `$AllUsers` and test them for the `Where-Object` filter.

Instead of using an array and `Where-Object`, consider loading all users into a hashtable:

```
# Only need to run this once, before the loop
$AllLogonsTable = @{}
$AllUsers |ForEach-Object {
    # Check if the hashtable already contains an item associated with the user name
    if(-not $AllLogonsTable.ContainsKey($_.SamAccountName)){
        # Before adding the first item, create an array we can add subsequent items to
        $AllLogonsTable[$_.SamAccountName] = @()
    }

    # Add the item to the array associated with the username
    $AllUsersTable[$_.SamAccountName] += $_
}

foreach($user in $users){
    # This will be _much faster_ than $AllUsers |Where-Object ...
    $allLogons = $AllLogonsTable[$user]
}
```

Hashtables have *crazy-fast* **lookups** - finding an object *by key* is much faster that using `Where-Object` on an array.

Comment: I have no experience with hashtables, so forgive me if this doesn't make sense: the `if(-not...)` code will basically group all the same usernames together? otherwise it'll create a new entry in the table? Also thanks!

Comment: Also would it make sense to just create the hashtable as I'm getting the users from the DCs? or does that come with an additional cost over doing it your way?

Comment: @YizBorol yeah, the `if(-not ...)` statement just ensures that we create a new array associated with the user name. You could create the hashtable upfront and then have each DC-specific result-set add directly to the hashtable, but micro-optimizing that part is probably not worth it in itself (remember, it only needs to be done _once_). Show us your code to populate `$AllUsers` if you want further help with it :)

Comment: Thank you! using the hashtable shaved off 30-40 min, it now takes about 1-2 min to complete the finding of inactive users! I only used write-progress because it was taking so long and I wanted to make sure it wasn't getting stuck somewhere, so I'll remove it now.

I'll mess around with the `$allusers` hashtable on my own, if I can't figure it out I'll make a new question about it. Thank you again, I'm gonna brush up on hashtables they're magical!

Comment: @YizBorol They are magical indeed! It used to be such a common occurence for me ([filtering AD results](https://blog.iisreset.me/powershell-caching-strategies/)) that I ended up writing [PSCache](https://github.com/IISResetMe/PSCache), you might want to take a look at that as well :)

Comment: So I tried this with a larger list and it appears that the hashtable is not much faster afterall... it chokes on this line `$finalLogon = $allLogons| Sort-Object LastLogon -Descending |Select-Object -First 1` because it appears that it's not actually accessing the records until that point, if I try `$allUsersTable[$user]` the first time it takes like 2 sec's per record the second time I run the command it spits them all out at once.

Comment: After doing a little more testing it appears that the line `$finalLogon = $allUsersTable[$user]| Sort-Object LastLogon -Descending |Select-Object -First 1` takes about 5 seconds per `$user` and I suspect most of it is spent retrieving the individual records. I'm not sure why it chokes like this though. each key now contains 8 arrays instead of just 3 but the total number of keys hasn't changed really (still ~6000)